# GAPI is Shutting Down Need A Lightweight PHP API for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

This is the question for GAPI users which shut down yesterday:

https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface

**GAPI - Google Analytics API PHP Interface** was a simple yet powerfull Google Analytics library. It was using the old API and required full Google username and password which was really old fashioned but it was working like a charm. bUT here we are, our GAPI based codes gives the message:

> Failed to authenticate user AuthForInstalledApps

The only option is to use the oAuth2.0, so what we got here?

**Google Client Libray:** https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

The issue with this library is, it's a common library, not just for Analytics. So if you're going to use it just for Analytics, it has lots of unnecessary classes like, Fitness, Adsense, Book, Blogger? The good side was, we can use just one basic php class to do the whole work, now why do we need to use thousand lines of codes?

I really read lots of Q&A, tried nearly all the PHP classes for that issue but they all referenced Google Client Library. When I found [wanze's Analytics API](https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP) I was really excited because it's using Oauth 2.0 and an updated library but this line returned empty, so it didn't work.

```
$auth = $ga->auth->getAccessToken($code);
```

So here we are, looking for a lightweight PHP library just for Google Analytics, using oAuth2, what's your suggestions beside Client Library?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I described the problem, which part is spam to you? If you know any Analytics API like that please tell us or anything like GAPI. Dozens of projects now not working just because of that problem and I'm looking for a solution, so that's spam?

Comment: @ DalmTo SO needs to revise some if its rules

Comment: Correction: client login is shut down not GAPI.   You can access GAPI  with Oauth2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am maintainer and was contacted today regarding GAPI and the OAuth2 requirement. Just released [Version 2.0 on GitHub](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) from contributions from the community.

Version 2.0 is a straight port from 1.3/1.4 and should match your existing system. Note that OAuth2 will require you to [create a 'service account'](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) and then download a P12 file to upload to the server. Finally you will need to adjust the developers console, enable 'analytics API'. Finally give this new user 'Read and Analyse' permissions on the Google Analytics accounts you want to access.

Comment: Wow, that's great news! Thank you Stig, I'll test it as soon as possible, you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

Hello Have you tried working through the recently updated [Hello Analytics API for PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php)? It goes through two different authentication methods. The [web app](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php) and [service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php).

You will probably need to update the [underlying client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Comment: As I told in my question, the problem with Analytics API, it's not seperated from your Google Client API, which has dozens of unnecessary other classes for other Google services. I've used your example, get my data but I got 6mb of google classes which I've no idea what to use for. Before that issue, there was only just a php class file, why do I need hundreds of classes? That's my question. There should be another way really.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation and just made the switch to Google Client Libray: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. Trust me, its not bad at all. I prefer lightweight but its pretty easy to use and you don't see much of the excess weight. The reason I would recommend it, once you make the switch, you can leverage Google tools (Analytic Query editor for example) and documentation. Took me an hour or so to 'port' my code. Rather than using a service account and certificate, I just save and store my oauth access token.

This article can help you with setup: http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/ and the code for actually doing the analytics i have examples of here (in my answer): [Get function in Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535837/get-function-in-google-analytics-api/30562422#30562422)