# GAPI not working analytics error

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I followed the same steps as mentioned in the following link
[GAPI is Shutting Down Need A Lightweight PHP API for Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477341/gapi-is-shutting-down-need-a-lightweight-php-api-for-google-analytics/)
It was working fine for 2 months, now it stopped working for the website, it has the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed
>   to authenticate user. Error: "{ "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "Bad Request" } "' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/****.org/httpdocs/gapi.class.php:662 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/*****.org/httpdocs/gapi.class.php(54):
>   gapiOAuth2->fetchToken('230397972383-lv...', 'API Project-b8f...',
>   NULL) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/****.org/httpdocs/modules/analytics.filter.php(14):
>   gapi->__construct('230397972383-lv...', 'API Project-b8f...') #2
>   {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/***.org/httpdocs/modules/gapi.class.php on line 662

Please help me out on this
I had shared this link on github too
https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/138